# `map_blocks` leads to tuple indices error in Dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed, scientific-computing

I am trying to apply a simple operation in parallel on a datacube, but I keep running into
a `TypeError`.

This is my input datacube (called `dcube`):

```
<xarray.DataArray 'A' (time: 6, pol: 1, y: 823, x: 1296)>
dask.array<where, shape=(6, 1, 823, 1296), dtype=float64, chunksize=(6, 1, 823, 1000), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * pol      (pol) object 'HH'
  * y        (y) float64 3.653e+06 3.653e+06 3.653e+06 ... 3.652e+06 3.652e+06
  * x        (x) float64 1.047e+06 1.047e+06 1.047e+06 ... 1.049e+06 1.049e+06
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-11-05T06:44:35 ... 2020-12-08T16:42:42
    id       (time) <U51 dask.array<chunksize=(6,), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    orbit:       A
    transform:   (1.1987408006010196, 0.0, 1047472.9120438152, 0.0, -1.198740...
    crs:         {'proj': 'utm', 'zone': 10, 'datum': 'WGS84', 'units': 'm', ...
```

The function I am trying to compute over looks like this:

```
def compute_something(chunk):
    img1 = chunk[0] + 0.00001
    img2 = chunk[1] + 0.00001
    return da.log10(img1 / img2)
```

When I try running:

```
da.map_blocks(compute_something, dcube, dtype=np.float32).compute()
```

This is the error I see:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
    760 
    761                     try:
--> 762                         value = future.result()
    763                     except Exception:
    764                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _gather(self, futures, errors, direct, local_worker)
   1848                             exc = CancelledError(key)
   1849                         else:
-> 1850                             raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)
   1851                         raise exc
   1852                     if errors == "skip":

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Nothing in the traceback seems to indicate what the error is.

In order to understand the problem a bit more, I created this minimal example:

```
arr = da.from_array(xa.DataArray([np.random.random((200,200))]),(1,10,10))
```

[image: xarray]

Then I try to execute this simple function:

```
def fn(x):
   return x
```

When I try to distribute with `map_blocks` I get an assertion error:

```
AA = da.map_blocks(fn, arr).compute()
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in new_da_object(dsk, name, chunks, meta, dtype)
   5017         from ..dataframe.core import new_dd_object
   5018 
-> 5019         assert all(len(c) == 1 for c in chunks[1:])
   5020         divisions = [None] * (len(chunks[0]) + 1)
   5021         return new_dd_object(dsk, name, meta, divisions)

AssertionError:
```

This leads me to think perhaps my understanding of how `map_blocks` works are lacking. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update / Edit:

After a little more investigation I have discovered that if the chunk type is `ndarray` everything works our perfectly, but if the chunk type is `xarray` it doesn't. Not sure why this is, how one can interconvert; but if I initialize `arr` as:

```
arr = da.from_array(np.random.random((200,200)))
```

`map_blocks` works perfectly. But if it contains an `xarray` it doesn't